# how to add to a application's development.rb config from in a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm making a gem that adds commonly used gems for development such as the bullet gem.

I want to add to the application's development.rb config file so I can configure the bullet gem with out having to do that from in the application's config file.

From what I can tell the application's development config file is named spaced to the application name ("SomeApp::Application.configure"). So how would I best add this file dynamically from in a gem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to set your gem up as a [rails engine](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html) by creating a class that inherits from `Rails::Engine` and making sure it gets included by the gem when it loads.

Within your engine, you can do any setup work as part of an initializer block:

```
module MyGem
  class Engine < Rails::Engine
    initializer "my_gem.setup_environment" do |app|
      case Rails.env
      when 'development'
        # do something
      else
        # do something else
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

With Railtie. You can access a config object which shared between other Railties and application:

```rb
class MyRailtie < Rails::Railtie
  config.to_prepare do
    MyRailtie.setup!
  end
end
```

Comment: So if I only wanted this to effect the development vars how would that work?